# can we select two elements in dropdown in form of check boxes?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

can we select two elements in dropdown in form of check boxes by using List or any other way. Elements in the dropdown are in the form of check boxes.
Thanks in advance.

Tried but didn't find the solution.

Comment: Please provide the more detail, currently it's unclear what you want to achieve ? Provide `HTML` source and `code` that you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu input, .dropdown-menu label').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  });
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Option 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Option 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Option 3</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

use this code if you are using bootstrap